# MVVM light Xamarin Android - DialogService throws error

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android, mvvm-light

I am using MVVM ligth with Xamarin Android. If I want to show a message I get a   *Java.Lang.NullPointerException*.

**Sample Code:**

```
private void MeldenButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var ds = new DialogService();
        ds.ShowMessage("Test", "Testnachricht"); 
    }
```

In the original code it looks like this:

```
if (await this._dialogService.ShowMessage(
    string.Format("Soll die Musterbestellung \"{0}\" gelöscht werden?",
    this._musterBestellung.Bezeichnung), "Löschbestätigung", "Ja", "Nein",
                 null))
```

and I get the errormessage  *System.MissingMethodException: Method 'Builder.SetOnDismissListener' not found.*

Any ideas?

Have an nice Weekend
Peter

FIND the answer myself:
*Java.Lang.NullPointerException* was thrown because the activit is not a ***ActivitBase*** !!!

*System.MissingMethodException: Method 'Builder.SetOnDismissListener' not found.* is thrown because this function was introduced in Level 17 and I try to use the DialogService with API-Level 16. Stupid error of me!

Sorry!

Comment: You can add an answer to your own question and approve it, so everybody sees your solution right away

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**FIND the answer myself:
Java.Lang.NullPointerException was thrown because the activit is not a ActivitBase !!!

System.MissingMethodException: Method 'Builder.SetOnDismissListener' not found. is thrown because this function was introduced in Level 17 and I try to use the DialogService with API-Level 16. Stupid error of me!
**